# Boot menu disappear after changing default OS

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, dualboot

I had windows 10 (A) installed on primary hard drive. Then I installed another Windows 10 (B) on other hard drive. So now I have 2 win10 installations and boot menu like this:

```
Windows 10 on volume 1 (B) (default)
Windows 10 on volume 3 (A)
```

But I want to change the default OS, and make A as default. I tried to change it in menu and msconfig.

- When I change default OS to A - Computer boots in system A only
  without boot menu. Boot menu dissapear.
- When I change default OS to B - Computer boots in boot menu, and the
  to default B.

How to make default system A and keep boot menu?

Here are my boot settings from os A:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Диспетчер загрузки Windows
--------------------
идентификатор           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {f4c6f6b7-1f97-11eb-87a3-8f4665afde5a}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Загрузка Windows
-------------------
идентификатор           {default}
device                  partition=M:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {f4c6f6b9-1f97-11eb-87a3-8f4665afde5a}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=M:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {f4c6f6b7-1f97-11eb-87a3-8f4665afde5a}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Загрузка Windows
-------------------
идентификатор           {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  ru-RU
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {f4c6f6b5-1f97-11eb-87a3-8f4665afde5a}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Here are my hard disks and volumes from os B:
[disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGyaD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using old style black and white boot menu instead of metro style menu.
First, I have renamed the systems. Than I run command in console:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes.
```

Now I have boot menu every time, no matter what OS is default.